# How find the peek value of a image plot? (Plot Digitizer)

Tags: image-processing, conv-neural-network, ocr, image-charts

I want to extract the peek value from a plot automatically.
I searched web plot digitizer and other programs and packages, however none of them gives points on the plot automatically. Is there any way to achieve this by using image processing such as CNN ?
I am thinking to make custom filters to find peek point.
Thanks in advance.

Sample plot

[image]

Comment: I see some boring red blobs which seem pointless. And some yellow blobs. I have no idea what you are trying to find nor how the image relates to your question. Maybe you could add an additional image showing what you want to find, please? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

**Algorithm**

1. convert to gray-scale  and binarize
2. find coorditates of  a white pixel   (x,y) where y is minimal nonzero values
3. add to y the blob radius y=y+r
4. make the scale transformation from range [0,image_height]  to your range [0,25]
5. calculate new value of y    under the transformation